# How to install php 5 and php 7 in openSuse(linux)?

Tags: php, opensuse

I want to install php 5 and php 7 in openSuse but I am a newbie in linux. I know is possible to install php5 and php7 on openSuse but I have no idea how to install it. I have done a lot of research in google but I am out of luck.

openSuse version:

```
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
VERSION="20170620"
ID=opensuse
ID_LIKE="suse"
VERSION_ID="20170620"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you mention php5 **and** php7. PHP5 is now past "End of Life" and will receive no new updates, including security fixes. As such, you probably shouldn't be installing it at all.

If you insist on installing both versions at the same time, you are looking at a complicated setup, not something for a "newbie in linux" to start off with.

As for installing PHP7, it's the same as installing anything else that is a standard part of openSUSE:

1. Open the main menu and find the entry for `YaST`, which might be called `Administrator Settings` and is probably in the `Settings` section and the `System` section of the `Applications` menu
   [image: Settings menu] [image: Settings Menu] [image: Settings Menu]
2. Click on that, provide the password if needed
   [image: Password dialog]
3. Click on `Software Management` in the right side of the window
   [image: YaST Dialog]
4. In the new window, in the top left corner, look for a box with a `Search` button next to it.
5. Type php7 in the box
   [image: Software Management]
6. Click on `Search`
7. In the list that shows up on the main, right side, panel, find and click on the check box next to php7
8. Click on `Accept` in the lower right corner of the window.
9. After the installation finishes, click on `Finish` and close the windows you opened

Note: If the installer needs anything else to make php work which is not already installed on your system, it will automatically select the missing things and open a dialog box listing what was added when you click on `Accept` in step 8. You can accept those changes as well, and then let it finish installing.

<sub>Licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20170220232407/https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)</sub>

Comment: because the linux already installed php5 and my senior want me to install php7 without replace php5

Comment: For security, as well as for any future development/programming you should upgrade the php5 to php7. Just to be sure, the php5 installed might be `php5-ZendFramework` which is a totally different thing. Assuming it's correctly listed, you should update the OS itself as well.

Comment: @ Gypsy Spellweaver, how to update the current php5 to php7?

Comment: Use YaST, as given. If it doesn't force you to remove php5, just mark the php5 entries for removal. Right-click will give options.

Comment: @ Gypsy Spellweaver, upgrade to php7 already, thanks for your help